# Using Moq for an indexer property causes InvalidCastException from Castle

Tags: c#, moq

When trying to use Moq to setup an indexer property, the underlying Castle library throws an InvalidCastException.  I am using Moq 4.0.10827, the details follow.  Thanks in advance if anyone can help me get the simple test (below) to run.   I am rewriting unit tests with Moq and I am trying to re-do the test for the following method:

```
public INetwork GetInputNetwork(IInputPortMgr inPortMgr)
{
    var port = inPortMgr[0];
    return port.InputNetwork;
}
```

The IInputPortMgr interface is as follows:

```
public interface IInputPortMgr
{        
    IInputPort this[int index] { get; }
}
```

The test I wrote (and tried numerous variations) can be summarized by:

```
[Test]
public void GetInputNetwork_Returns_InputNetwork_From_InputPort()
{
    var mockInPortMgr = new Mock<IInputPortMgr>();
    var mockInPort = new Mock<IInputPort>();
    var mockNet = new Mock<INetwork>();

    mockInPortMgr.Setup(m => m[0]).Returns(mockInPort.Object);  // exception here
    mockInPort.Setup(m => m.InputNetwork).Returns(mockNet.Object);

    // Assertions Here
}
```

But when run the unit test fails because an exception is thrown by the line

`mockInPortMgr.Setup(m => m[0]).Returns(mockInPort.Object);`

The details of the exception are:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Reflection.CustomAttributeTypedArgument]' to type 'System.Array'.
at System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder.EmitValue(BinaryWriter writer, Type type, Object value)
at System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder.InitCustomAttributeBuilder(ConstructorInfo con, Object[] constructorArgs, PropertyInfo[] namedProperties, Object[] propertyValues, FieldInfo[] namedFields, Object[] fieldValues)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AttributeUtil.CreateBuilder(CustomAttributeData attribute)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AttributeUtil.<GetNonInheritableAttributes>d__0.MoveNext()
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.MetaProperty.BuildPropertyEmitter(ClassEmitter classEmitter)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.CompositeTypeContributor.ImplementProperty(ClassEmitter emitter, MetaProperty property, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.CompositeTypeContributor.Generate(ClassEmitter class, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithoutTargetGenerator.GenerateType(String typeName, Type proxyTargetType, Type[] interfaces, INamingScope namingScope)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.GenerateCode(Type proxyTargetType, Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(ICallInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments)
at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__0()
at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
at Tests.Psi.Type6.Fx.Type6Fixture.GetInputNetwork() in Type6Fixture.cs: line 293
```

Any ideas or could anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug](http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/DYNPROXY-151) in the version of the Castle DynamicProxy that is merged into the moq binary (Castle.Core 2.5.0.0). It looks to affect attributes that accepts a `params` argument. I am assuming `IInputPort` is decorated with such an attribute since the code is not provided?

You could compile moq with the latest version of Castle.Core (3.0.0.0) (*ideal*).

Or (*less ideal*), download the latest moq release from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/detail?name=Moq.4.0.10827.Final.zip&can=2&q=), which includes a moq.dll version without `Castle.Core` embedded. Reference this in your project along with [Castle.Core 3.0.0.0](https://nuget.org/packages/Castle.Core) and add the following binding redirect in your app.config. Since this is a major point upgrade I can't vouch for it's backward compatibility, but I tested this with your code (and an `IInputPort` interface decorated with an attribute that surfaces the bug in 2.5.0.0) and it worked.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" 
                          publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" 
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.5.0.0" 
                         newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```